# Mapping attributes from Map Key on Element Collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Let's say i have a class called **Collect** with the following attribute:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="product_id")
@Column(name="quantity")
@CollectionTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="order_id"))
//The value of the map stores the quantity of each product.
private Map<Product, Integer> collectedProducts;
```

And this gives me following table:

```
+----------------+------------+------------+
|       order_id |   quantity | product_id |
+----------------+------------+------------+
|          50006 |          1 |         14 |
|          50006 |          3 |         15 |
+----------------+------------+------------+
```

What if i want another column called 'weight' like:

```
+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
|       order_id |   quantity | product_id |     weight |
+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
|          50006 |          1 |         14 |       3.00 |
|          50006 |          3 |         15 |       5.00 |
+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Where the weight is variable. That is, it's not stored in the 'product' table. I want to set the weight and store in this table. Like:

```
product.setWeight(5.00);
collectedProducts.put(product, quantity);
repository.save(order);
```

Any idea on how can i do it? I achieved this by creating another `Map <Product,Weight>` and mapping this as an `ElementCollection`, but this gave me another table in the database and i want to know if there is a simple way.

Comment: Create an extra entity if you want to add "extra columns", and map the real data (weight + number). JPA does nothing special here ... get your O-O right and all will map fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created another class called `Quantity` and anotted it as  `@Embeddable`

```
    @Embeddable
    public class Quantity {

    private int quantity;
    private double weight;

 //getters and setter ommited;

    }
```

Then in my `Collect` class, just mapped this new class as my map value type:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="product_id")
@CollectionTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="order_id"))
Map<Product,Quantity> collectedProducts;
```